# How to Generate XML from Database

Tags: sql, xml

I am fetching data from two tables CARRIER_IFTA ,IFTA_NAME.
 My Select Query is like below..

```
SELECT t1.IFTA_LICENSE_NUMBER,t1.IFTA_BASE_STATE,t2.NAME_TYPE,t2.NAME
from CARRIER_IFTA t1 inner join  IFTA_NAME t2
    on t1.IFTA_LICENSE_NUMBER=t2.IFTA_LICENSE_NUMBER
```

My Data is coming in this way...

```
IFTA_LICENSE_NUMBER   IFTA_BASE_STATE  NAME_TYPE  NAME
--------------------------------------------------------
630908333                 US            LG        XYZ
630908333                 US            MG        PQR
730908344                 US            LG        ABC
```

Now using XSLT I want to generate XML like this

```
<T0019>
  <IFTA_ACCOUNT>
    <IFTA_LICENSE_NUMBER>630908333</IFTA_LICENSE_NUMBER>
    <IFTA_BASE_STATE>US</IFTA_BASE_STATE>
    <IFTA_NAME>
       <NAME_TYPE>LG<NAME_TYPE>
       <NAME>XYZ</NAME>
    </IFTA_NAME>
    <IFTA_NAME>
       <NAME_TYPE>MG<NAME_TYPE>
       <NAME>PQR</NAME>
    <IFTA_NAME>
  </IFTA_ACCOUNT>
  <IFTA_ACCOUNT>
     <IFTA_LICENSE_NUMBER>730908344</IFTA_LICENSE_NUMBER>
     <IFTA_BASE_STATE>US</IFTA_BASE_STATE>
     <IFTA_NAME>
       <NAME_TYPE>LG<NAME_TYPE>
       <NAME>ABC</NAME>
    </IFTA_NAME>
  </IFTA_ACCOUNT>     

</T0019>
```

i have used below xslt but it is not giveng me desire result ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/ROWSET">
        <xsl:element name="T0019">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="IFTAACCOUNT"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="IFTAACCOUNT">
        <xsl:element name="IFTAACCOUNT">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="IFTA_CARRIER_ID_NUMBER"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="IFTA_LICENSE_NUMBER">
            <xsl:element name="IFTA_LICENSE_NUMBER">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="IFTA_BASE_STATE">
            <xsl:element name="IFTA_BASE_STATE">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="IRP_NAME">
     <IRP_NAME>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="NAME"/>    
        <xsl:apply-templates select="NAME_TYPE"/>       
     </IRP_NAME>            
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="NAME">
            <xsl:element name="NAME">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="NAME_TYPE">
            <xsl:element name="NAME_TYPE">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but it is not giving desire result ...

Please help me ...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Can you give a sample of the XML that you are passing to the XSLT? Your query returns a simple rowset, and so must at least be converted XML somewhere before applying the XSLT.

Comment: Actully I am trying to convert it directly from Database to XML using XSLT . Should I generate intermidiate XML and then convert that to My Result xml ?

Comment: Yes, XSLT can only transform XML to something else. I'm not aware of a way to use XSLT to read something other than XML.

Answer (score 1):

Most RDBMS provides builtin tools to return straight XML without the need for XSL. Which one are you using? Consult its documentation. If it is for example MySQL, then you need the [`--xml` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_xml).

Comment: That's right I am using Oracles's OracleXMLQuery to generate xml from Oracle's Table.

Comment: Oh, you actually want to transform one XML to another XML? I don't do Oracle, but as far as I know, you could customize the XML output generated by Oracle?

Comment: No, I want to generate XML from Oracle Database using OracleXMLQuery.